# Facebook cron job upload daily photo to multiple users

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, cron, facebook-php-sdk

I've developed a small faceinhole type app and where a daily photo is uploaded to an album with a count down pasted in the picture everyday until the day of the event. 
Im trying to acheive daily upload and post to wall of every user ive saved but it seems to fail everytime.. the app request for offline access and publish stream.. its saves access_token and user id. When cron job runs everyday it gets 1 or 2 successfull uploads and then it gets error 505 page not found. Heres my code. Any ideas on how to change this in order it to work?

```
   $app_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
   $app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";


$sel=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faceinhole WHERE imagen!='' AND activo=1");
while($as=mysql_fetch_array($sel)){
     $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true,
    'domain' => "mydomain.com"
    ));
    extract($as);
if(is_file($imagen)){
 $future=mktime(20,0,0,10,14,2011);
 $now = time();
 $timeleft = $future-$now;
 $daysleft=floor($timeleft/60/60/24);
 list($w,$h)=getimagesize($imagen); 
 $imagen2=imagecreatefromjpeg($imagen);
 imagepng($imagen2,$imagen.".png");
 $imagen3=imagecreatefrompng($imagen.".png");
 $color = imagecolorallocate($imagen3, 58, 221, 2);
 imagettftext ( $imagen3 , 64 , 0 , 124 ,315 , $color , "Gotham-Ultra.ttf" , "$daysleft" );
 $prefijo2 = substr(md5(uniqid(rand())),0,6);
 $connum="fotos/".$prefijo."_feis_num.png";
 imagepng($imagen3,$connum);

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
if($album_id!=""){
    $album_uid=$album_id;
    }else{
    $album_details = array(
    'access_token'  => "$access_token",
            'message'=> "Mis camisetas de los Juegos Panamericanos Guadalajara 2011. Viste la camiseta Panamericana para tu perfil de facebook aquí -> http://facebook.com/galeriasgdl?sk=app_$app_id",
            'name'=> 'Mis camisetas Panamericanas'
    );
    try{
$create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);
    }catch(Exeption $e){

        }
$album_uid = $create_album['id'];
mysql_query("UPDATE faceinhole SET album_id='$album_uid' WHERE user_id='$user_id'")or die(mysql_error());;
}
$photo_details = array(
    'access_token'  => "$access_token",
    'message'=> "Estoy a $daysleft días de los Juegos Panamericanos Guadalajara 2011. Viste la camiseta Panamericana para tu perfil de facebook aquí -> http://facebook.com/galeriasgdl?sk=app_$app_id"
);
$file=$connum; 
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);
try{$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);}catch(Exeption $e){}

}
}
```

Comment: do you mean 404 error instead of 505 for the HTTP status code?

Comment: Question for you. If you run the script manually (and not via a cron job) do you get the error or do the pictures upload correctly?

Comment: If i run it manually with no loop it successfully uploads photos, the loop is the problem thats when i get the 404 i think error.

Comment: Have you tried  to put some 'sleep(3000)' between the calls so the FB server won't hit some threshold?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic posting, even with consent, is frowned upon by the Policy Team.